# How to disable write protection in my flash drive?

Tags: usb, write-protect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I remove a USB drive’s write protection?](https://superuser.com/questions/531516/how-do-i-remove-a-usb-drives-write-protection)

I own a SanDisk Ultra 32GB and been using it for quite a while now. It has been a while since I've used it and has suddenly become write protected. Tried a lot of solutions as well but to no avail. All that I've done are:

- No switch in the flash drive
- Both format and "low level formatting" since it is write protected
- Creating WriteProtect folder and changing it to 0
- Repair_Neo2.9.exe says "USB Flash Disk not found!"
- Diskpart>attributes disk clear readonly will say that the attributes are cleared but   remains write protected

I saw a post saying that he/she tried to remove readonly attributes in the diskpart solution and formatted the flash drive but I have no idea how he/she did it.

I hope that somebody could help me with this.

Comment: What operation system you use ?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate.